# Lazy load property in IoC service

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, lazy-loading

IoC service should retrieve information from DB that

- never changed during session. May be this is constant value.
- is time expensive

Should I use in this case Pattern "lazy load" for property that encapsulates access to service method? For example:

```
public interface IMyDbConstantService {
   string MyDbConstant {get;} 
   string GetMyDbConstant();
}

public class MyDbConstantService: IMyDbConstantService {

   public string MyDbConstant 
   { 
      get
      {
        // Implementing lazy load pattern
        return myDbConstant  ?? (myDbConstant = this.GetMyDbConstant());
      }
   }


   public string GetMyDbConstant() {
     // time expensive operation
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume myDbConstant is a field?  You don't declare it anywhere.  I would make it a private static field--you *may* also need to add locks around updates to it.

I would also remove the getter in the interface and implementation, and just put the lazy initialization directly in the GetMyDBConstant method.

As far as whether this is a good idea: you haven't provided enough information to say one way or another.  Does it make more sense to load on on first use, or can you load it at application startup, possibly in a background thread?